# Cambiar GAM a español

Tags: genexus

Estoy incorporando GAM a mi aplicación y el cliente me pide de que el GAM se muestre en español.
¿Alguien sabe alguna forma de hacer que el GAM se vea en español?
Gracias.

Comment: Que versión de GX es? debe tener un selector de idiomas el Genexus Access Manager, si no tiene creo que podes ingresar a la carpeta donde está el proyecto y modificar el archivo con Sublime o VS code.

Comment: Hola Paco. Estoy con Gx 18 U3